# Is there a standard way to display qualified Dublin Core meta in HTML meta tags?

Tags: html, meta-tags, dublin-core

DC includes an element called "Date".  You display it like this:

```
<meta name="dc.Date" content="2011-06-28" />
```

But the idea of qualifiers lets you have a "Date Created" and "Date Updated."  But is there a way to embed this correctly?  I've seen this a couple ways:

```
<meta name="dc.Date" content="(Scheme=Created) 2011-06-28" />
<meta name="dc.Date" content="2011-06-28" scheme="Created" />
```

Is there a standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read the spec these things you are talking about are **Element Refinements** (like `created`, `modified`, etc. for `date`).

> *Element Refinement:* These qualifiers
>   make the meaning of an element
>   narrower or more specific. A refined
>   element shares the meaning of the
>   unqualified element, but with a more
>   restricted scope. A client that does
>   not understand a specific element
>   refinement term should be able to
>   ignore the qualifier and treat the
>   metadata value as if it were an
>   unqualified (broader) element. The
>   definitions of element refinement
>   terms for qualifiers must be publicly
>   available.

from [dublincore.org](http://dublincore.org/documents/usageguide/qualifiers.shtml)

[The spec suggests](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcq-html/#sect-3) two equivalent ways of writing:

```
<meta name="DC.Date.modified" content="2001-07-18" />
<meta name="DCTERMS.modified" content="2001-07-18" />
```

---

A **Scheme** that you mention is used to define encoding, formatting of data. For example for dates, it can either be `DCMI Period` or `W3C-DTF` as seen on [this page](http://dublincore.org/documents/usageguide/qualifiers.shtml).

> *Encoding Scheme:* These qualifiers
>   identify schemes that aid in the
>   interpretation of an element value.
>   These schemes include controlled
>   vocabularies and formal notations or
>   parsing rules. A value expressed using
>   an encoding scheme will thus be a
>   token selected from a controlled
>   vocabulary (e.g., a term from a
>   classification system or set of
>   subject headings) or a string
>   formatted in accordance with a formal
>   notation (e.g., "2000-01-01" as the
>   standard expression of a date). If an
>   encoding scheme is not understood by a
>   client or agent, the value may still
>   be useful to a human reader. The
>   definitive description of an encoding
>   scheme for qualifiers must be clearly
>   identified and available for public
>   use.

from [dublincore.org](http://dublincore.org/documents/usageguide/qualifiers.shtml)

They can be used like:

```
<meta name="DC.date" scheme="DCTERMS.W3CDTF" content="2001-07-18" />
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you.  However, I've actually seen the two examples above that I've provided.  Based on your information, they are incorrect -- is this right?

Comment: @Deane Well, according to `dublincore.org` it seems that `Created` is certainly not a `scheme`.